# How do you remove the contact-info page from a plone site?

Tags: plone

Every new plone site as a /contact-info/ url with a generic email form on it.

Spambots can easily find this and use it spam the webmaster with malicious emails (specifically note that the 'subject' can be set in the email).

This old thread http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/modify-or-disable-site-contact-form-td7258555.html suggests that you can simply update the template so it is an empty page. However, this is not enough to prevent spam.

```
wget http://localhost:8080/contact-info --post-data "sender_fullname=d&sender_from_address=doug@localhost.com&subject=d&message=d&form.submitted=1"
```

Will still send email on the form handler.

How do you completely disable this form handler?

edit: I see you can modify the form handler script at:

```
/portal_skins/plone_form_scripts/send_feedback_site/manage_main 
/portal_skins/custom/contact-info
```

To generate a custom handler script and replace the default actions. However, this doesn't really remove the page, it just makes it do nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you must customize is not the template but the end point the `send_feedback_site` script.

Replace the whole script code with:

```
from zExceptions import NotFound
raise NotFound()
```

Or probably `Unauthorized` is better.

Comment: Does it matters which one you customise? both is kind of a hack, since plone should provide a proper solution for this.

Comment: IMO it matters. If you customize only the `contact-info` form a bot can call directly the `send_feedback_site` script.
Apart that: yes... Plone must handle this natively (or you can use collective.captchacontactinfo)

Comment: Using z3c.jbot allows you to override a core Plone page without touching the zmi or core packages. I use it to rework quite a few pieces of Plone core. 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot

Comment: True, but overriding a CMF skin item with z3c.jbot is not so convenient. I mean: it's equally simple to be done. Also: customizing send_to stuff can be done TTW using ZMI.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing—remove default contact form. I replaced the script as said above. No results yet, possibly cache issue. My question is would deleting the CMF Action "Contact" from portal_actions/site_actions also work?

Comment: @Christina no, this way you only remove a link to the form, not the form itself. A bot that "knows" how Plone is done can still access the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running nginx or apache in front of your Plone site you could write a redirect rule for that URL. This could then be added to your 'standard' buildout so that it always is there for new sites.